# Is there a way to hide the section numbers in the TOC and the sections themselves?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, titlesec, unnumbered-sections

I don't know latex at all and I'm using pandoc to convert from markdown to pdf.

Here's how I do converting:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -V mainfont="Liberation Sans" --toc -N -V toc-title="Мундарижа" -V colorlinks -V urlcolor=NavyBlue -V geometry:"top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm" -f markdown+hard_line_breaks -H ./head.tex ./document.md -o document.pdf
```

head.tex (I got this from the internet somewhere):

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

\let\oldtoc\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\oldtoc\newpage}
```

The result is the below. All is good. But I need to remove numbers within the red:
[image]

I can achieve this by adding {.unnumbered} class. But then I get my links broken (clicking to any TOC link gets me to the first page).

What should I be doing? Please help...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Without seeing a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue we can only guess, sorry. Please show a short compilable TeX code in your question.

Comment: @Mensch, thank you for reaching out. Did you mean to show the full LaTeX code I'm using? If so, the head.tex file is all I used. And the document.md file is a standard markdown file with simple formatting. Sorry, I'm really clueless...

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you want to remove section number from TOC *and* the section titles themselves? Then you should just *not* use the `-N` switch when calling pandoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this has nothing to do with LaTeX but with your (wrong?) usage of pandoc. You should familiarize yourself with what the different switches in your command line to call pandoc do.
As the [documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) states, the switch `-N` does the following:

> **-N, --number-sections**
>
> Number section headings in LaTeX, ConTeXt, HTML, Docx, ms, or EPUB output. By default, sections are not numbered. Sections with class unnumbered will never be numbered, even if `--number-sections` is specified.

So you explicitly tell pandoc to use section numbers but actually do not want them. So just don't use that option.